# CodeMirror-UI in smartGWT tab

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, codemirror

I have a question regarding the integration of CodeMirror UI in a smartGWT tab.

Basically, I can't display the CodeMirror-UI editor inside the textarea element I attached to a smartGWT tab. Here's what I did:

1. I installed CodeMirror-UI as described on [its page](https://github.com/jagthedrummer/codemirror-ui), correcting the paths to match my project's directory hierarchy
2. I wrote a js script in my project's main html (at head) :

   ```
   <head>
   ...
    <script>
     function fireEditor()
     {
      var textarea = window.document.getElementById('tab_editor' );
      var uiOptions = { path : 'codemirror-ui/js/', searchMode : 'inline' };
      var codeMirrorOptions = { mode: 'javascript' };
      var editor = new CodeMirrorUI(textarea,uiOptions,codeMirrorOptions);
     }
    </script>
   </head>
   ```
3. I invoked the script while opening a (smartGWT) tab:

   ```
   // create a smartGWT tab
   Tab tab = new Tab("tab");
   tab.setID("tab");
   tab.setCanClose(true);

   // put the CodeMirror UI inside the smartGWT tab
   // create a smartGWT canvas
   Canvas tabContent = new Canvas();
   tabContent.setID("tabc");
   tabContent.setWidth100();
   tabContent.setHeight100();

   // use a GWT HTMLPanel to attach new html elements to the smartGWT canvas
   // and invoke the fireEditor() function to load the CodeMirror UI
   HTMLPanel editorContainer = new HTMLPanel(
    "<div id=\"editor_container\">"
    + "<textarea id=\"tab_editor\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%\" onload=\"fireEditor()\">"
    + "</textarea>"
    + "</div>");
   editorContainer.setWidth("100%");
   editorContainer.setHeight("100%");
   ```

running from a browser (I'm using firefox - iceweasel 10.0.10), this results in a smartGWT tab that shows an empty textarea element.
Checking with firebug, the area within the smartGWT tab contains the HTML I specified in the HTMLPanel, but no CodeMirror UI is shown.

What am I missing?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, with gwt 2.4.0, smartgwt 3.0p, and codemirror ui 0.0.19 from its git repo (which itself uses CodeMirror 2.3).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

First of all, there is no "onload" event for an html textarea element, so the code

```
    HTMLPanel editorContainer = new HTMLPanel(
    "<div id=\"editor_container\">"
    + "<textarea id=\"tab_editor\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%\" onload=\"fireEditor()\">"
    + "</textarea>"
    + "</div>");
```

will just place a textarea in the HTMLPanel, without calling "fireEditor()".
Replacing "onload" with "onclick" does the trick: once the textarea element shows up, click on it, and the CodeMirrorUI will show up as well.

Problem: I need to visualize the CodeMirrorUI interface automatically, ergo the "onclick" approach is useless.

To accomplish this task, I need to somehow modify the DOM of the smartGWT tab, replacing its inner html with CodeMirrorUI's html.
I found this documentation very helpful: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/DomIntegration.html

this is the resulting code:

1) I kept the js script in my project's main html (at head) :

```
    <head>
    ...
    <script>
      function fireEditor()
      {
        var textarea = window.document.getElementById('tab_editor' );
        var uiOptions = { path : 'codemirror-ui/js/', searchMode : 'inline' };
        var codeMirrorOptions = { mode: 'javascript' };
        var editor = new CodeMirrorUI(textarea,uiOptions,codeMirrorOptions);
      }
    </script>
    </head>
```

2) I created a new class -"MyEditor", following the example found in the documentation link I mentioned above :

```
    public class MyEditor extends Canvas {
       private String editor_id = null;

   private static native void replace(String editor) /*-{
          $wnd.fireEditor(editor);
   }-*/;

   public MyEditor(Integer num) {
          editor_id = "editor_" + num;
          setRedrawOnResize(false);
   }

   @Override
   public String getInnerHTML() {
          return "<textarea id=\"" + editor_id + "\"" + "style=\"width:100%;height:100%\"></textarea>";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw() {
          MyEditor.replace(editor_id);
   }

    }
```

3) finally, I filled the smartGWT tab with an instance of MyEditor:

```
    // create a smartGWT tab
    Tab tab = new Tab("tab");
    tab.setID("tab");
    tab.setCanClose(true);

    MyEditor editor = new MyEditor(tabNumber); // an integer number
    tab.setPane(editor);
```

Tested. Working.